# How works return -code $value from the proc in TCL

Tags: return, tcl, proc

I must use a proc Z, which returns something like "return -code 2"  $something , but I can't understand how it's works.

```
proc X {} {
    puts "X - in"
    Y
    puts "X - out"
}
proc Y {} {
    puts "Y - in"
    Z
    puts "Y - out"
}
proc Z {} {
    puts "Z - in"
    return -code 2 "some value"
    puts "Z - out"
}
X
```

Output is :

```
X - in
Y - in
Z - in
X - out
```

I can't change return in proc Z, but I also want that it continues his work in proc Y and puts "Y-out". Can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` command conceptually raises an exception (of type `return`, which corresponds to the `TCL_RETURN` result code in the Tcl C API) that is trapped by the procedure (strictly, by the procedure hull that does things like callframe management and argument marshalling) in which it runs to make that do something. In the case of a normal `return`, it simply makes the procedure return that value, but when the `-code` option is provided, it can direct the procedure to do something else; this is done *after* the callframe has been popped from the Tcl call stack.

Because `2` is the actual value of the `TCL_RETURN` result code, it means that it is telling the procedure hull (i.e., the overall `Z` procedure) to behave like it was a simple call to `return`, which is why `puts "Y - out"` isn't being executed; there's a return exception being processed as a result of the execution of `Z`. (FWIW, `return -code 2` is pretty rare. `return -code 1`/`return -code error` is much more common, as it is a way of getting an *error* exception to be thrown, which is useful because stack traces are only built by error exceptions.)

You can override this processing using `catch` or `try`. It's a bit easier to get this right with `try`, since `catch` is a fairly broad-brush primitive. Try this:

```
proc Y {} {
    puts "Y - in"
    try {
        Z
    } on return {msg} {
        puts "Z told us to return '$msg'"
    }
    puts "Y - out"
}
```

If you're just wanting to make a short piece of code work after the call but otherwise not interfere, `try`…`finally` is the right way:

```
proc Y {} {
    puts "Y - in"
    try {
        Z
    } finally {
        puts "Y - out"
    }
}
```

If you're using Tcl 8.5 (or before), you won't have `try`. Here's a version with `catch`:

```
proc Y {} {
    puts "Y - in"
    set code [catch {
        Z
    } msg]
    if {$code == 2} {
        puts "Z told us to return '$msg'"
    }
    puts "Y - out"
}
```

The problem with `catch` is that it is very easy to lose errors by accident.

Comment: There are other exception codes too — they're logically behind how `break` and `continue` work in loops, and also `exp_continue` in the Expect extension — though Tcl's implementation usually optimizes them out as much as possible, provided code can't observe that they exist.